# Is a text file with 16 leading binary bytes a "normal" file format?

Tags: linux, windows, file, text, format

I've encountered files with leading byte values as follows when viewed in a hex editor:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0f
```

I've seen this in 2 cases:

1. *.csproj.CopyComplete files.  My Windows .NET Xunit projects contain these files.  They consist of only 16 bytes with the sequential byte signature as shown above.
2. Macintosh text files (as generated from Excel file save in "Text (Macintosh) (*.txt)").  In this case the first 16 bytes follow the signature above, followed by the expected document text.

My understanding is that text files may have a leading binary byte signature if their encoding is not UTF-8.

Can anyone provide more information about this byte signature?

Comment: '*when viewed in a hex editor*" It helped if you indicated *which* hex editor and/or provided a screen snapshot. Most likely `00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f` is a column header displayed by the hex viewer, not part of the text file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Right you are!  My bad.  The *.CopyComplete files are 0-length, so the hex editor display misled me.